# Can't submit HTML form inside Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular

I'm trying to include static HTML form inside my Angular 2 (beta2) app but it doesn't do anything when I hit the submit button.

Here's the HTML I use:

```
<form action="upload_path" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="text" />
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

How can I enable my form to work with Angular2?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With

```
<form ngNoForm ...>
```

you can prevent Angular from handling the form.

Comment: You can derive it from the selector in https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm but I agree that it would be worth being mentioned explicitly.

Comment: this answer doesn't work with Angular form validation. Should use <form action="upload_path" method="POST" onsubmit="this.submit()">

Comment: onsubmit="this.submit()" is what did the trick for me as well

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use the `action` attribute of HTML form, you need to disable the behavior of the `NgForm` directive that catches the `submit` event and prevents it from being propagated. See this line: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form.ts#L81.

To do that simply add the `ngNoForm` attribute to your form:

```
<form ngNoForm action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <input name="q" value="test">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

In this case, a new window will be opened for your form submission.

That said, Angular2 tackles SPAs (Single Page Applications) and in most use cases, you need to stay in the same page when submitting a form. For such use cases, you can leverage the `submit` event with a submit button:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="companyForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    Name: <input [ngFormControl]="companyForm.controls.name"
           [(ngModel)]="company.name"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 10):

Angular 2 adds an event handler to forms *submit* event and blocks the forms form being sent. This is done for the sake of normal AJAX use case where you don't actually want to submit the form (and thus reload the page), but instead catch it on JavaScript and send an AJAX request (or handle the data other ways).

You can bypass this by using your custom event handler which will be called first and in which you send the form already before it goes to the Angular's handler.

To do this, you need to add `onsubmit="this.submit()"` on your form element like this:

```
<form action="upload_path" method="POST" onsubmit="this.submit()">
```

Comment: It was hard to find but this answer is the most elegant one I could find. It will submit the form in the same window (instead of opening another one like all other solutions I found) and also does not require you to disable ngForm (though I have not tested what kind of functionality loss you get exactly by overriding the event handler this way). Thus of course going against the point of a SPA by navigating away from it but if you can live with that, this will do.

Comment: Why is there a `this` being used in the template? I did a quick google and it does not seem standard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152290/using-this-keyword-in-angular-components-template If `this` is referring to the component, are you just calling a custom defined function in the TS file? If so I think you can omit the `this`.

Comment: @ahong Judging based on when this answer was written it must've been an Angular 2.0 beta thing to write it with explicit `this`.  Angular 2.0 was released only half a year later than this answer was written.

Comment: Makes sense... thanks, a good history lesson

Comment: thank you. I prefer this answer. It works well with Angular form validation